# Changed site URL and home URL and Wordpress not working now

Tags: php, wordpress

I changed my website's Home and Site URL in the Settings -> General Settings pane of the administration back-end and now it only pulls through plain text and doesn't load the admin panel at all.

None of the credentials in the `wp-config.php` file have been changed at all. At first it said something like "Error establishing a database connection" and that seemed to fix itself. But now the site doesn't pull through any stylesheets and I can't login to the back-end using `mysite.com/admin`.

Comment: It sounds like you put in the wrong URL, and it's unable to find the proper files. You can change it back following the directions at http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley I tried this solution by including the commands in the `functions.php` but had no success :(

Comment: I usually hardcode the url into `wp-config.php`, per the directions in that link. Give that a try.

Comment: No success again @JeremiahWinsley :(

Comment: Try checking the error logs, and make sure it's not a database issue that isn't showing up. Unless you have a non-standard configuration, e.g. themes or plugins in different directories than normal, changing the site url back to the original should be all that's necessary.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to work out the issue, so am voting to put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your wp-config.php

define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );